# How can I remove my down-vote I made by mistake

Tags: support

I recently accidentally down-voted an answer without realising (think it was because of a miss click when scrolling on the iOS app). The only issue is I cannot remove that down-vote now because of this error.

[image]

Would any mod/admin be kind enough to remove it (and give my back my 1 reputation) please?

Thanks for your help and any inconvenience I have caused.

The link to the post I down-voted is here: [Cannot access vital boot options on Mac Pro with OS X Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102271/cannot-access-vital-boot-options-on-mac-pro-with-os-x-lion/127955#127955) (it scrolls to the answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've edited the question slighly, you should be able to undo your vote now.

OTOH, down voting that answer isn't totally unjustified...

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean bi OTOH?

Comment: "On the other hand" :-) Honestly, the answer doesn't actually provide an answer to the problem, so I'm kind of surprised that it didn't gather more down votes.

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't even read the answer which is why I didn't want it down-voted. That's why I didn't down-vote.